# Calculate cell offset after rotate CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to create `UICollectionViewCell` with "rotate" effect, and i did that by rotate it center like that:

```
func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Double.pi * (degrees / 180.0))
}

class TimbreLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
        for attribute in layoutAttributes {
            attribute.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees: -6))
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

[image]

So far so good, now i want to calculate "white" space that you can see after cell is rotated, so i can increase it width by same amount. I guess that involve some math knowledge in which im not strong enough to handle it.

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking for. Is it the bounding box of a rotated rectangle?

Comment: @matt distance between screen edge to bottom left corner of cell.

Comment: What was the distance before the rotation? Was it zero?

Comment: Also need to know what point we are rotating around. Is it the center of the cell?

Comment: @matt it was 0, cell is actually bound to screen edges. Yes, i rotate center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

- Collection view width: `w`
- Rotation angle: `a`

Needed:

- Cell width: `cw`

Solution:

`cw = 2 * (w / cos(a) - w)`

**NB:** expected to work only in small angles (will not work if you will rotate your cell to 360). Also I tested it only in calc :). So you may want to doublecheck it.